# How to create newline on csv file from powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am stuck on a point where I have two array variables like this

`$name = @("A","B","C")`

`$roll = @("1","2","3")`

and I am trying to make a csv file with this data. I am using this code

```
$name = @("A","B","C")
$roll = @("1","2","3")
$report = New-Object psobject
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "$name"
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Roll" -Value "$roll"
$report | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\r.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But I have a output like this

> NAME | ROll
>
> A B C| 1 2 3

I want my output like this

> NAME | ROll
>
> A    |  1
>
> B    |  2
>
> C    |  3

Can any one have any idea how to do these... Please help me... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current code is creating the object, and adding the arrays `$name` and `$roll` as *single entries*.

It sounds like you want an entry for each value in your array. Assuming the arrays are the same length, you could iterate over the values:

```
$name = @("A","B","C")
$roll = @("1","2","3")

foreach($i in 0..($name.Count -1)){
    [array]$report += [pscustomobject] @{
        Name = $name[$i]
        Roll = $roll[$i]
    }
}

# screen output
# $report | Format-Table

$report | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\r.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Screen Output**

```
Name Roll
---- ----
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

Comment: @KunalMajumder NP! If it's resolved your issue, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$name = "A","B","C"
$roll = "1","2","3" 
$index = 0
$name | %{[pscustomobject]@{Name=$_;Roll=$roll[$index++]}} |Export-csv "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\r.csv" -NoType
```